# How do I float a div to the center?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to be able to center a div in the middle of a page but can't get it to work. I tried float: center; in css but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: None of these stuff is any help at all.

Answer (score 36):

There is no float: center; in css. Use margin: 0 auto; instead. So like this:

```
.mydivclass {
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: The class `wrapper` might confuse people. Edited.

Comment: Please note that you **must** set a width!

Comment: You also have to remove float.

Answer (score 16):

You can do it inline like this

```
<div style="margin:0px auto"></div>
```

or you can do it via class

```
<div class="x"><div>
```

in your css file or between `<style></style>` add this `.x{margin:0px auto}`

or you can simply use the center tag

```
  <center>
    <div></div>
  </center>
```

or if you using absolute position, you can do

```
.x{
   width: 140px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -70px; /*half the size of width*/
}
```

Comment: Please don't mention the CENTER element. It' been deprecated for over 10 years.

Comment: @Šime Did you know that Google still uses it along with font tags. View source on google page and you'll see.

Comment: @Sime nothing is wrong with the center element, except when you use it with XHTML or HTML5. It's not deprecated in HTML 4.

Comment: @Radek Yes it is: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER And it has been deprecated for over **11** years, to be more precise. Are you suggesting that it is OK to use deprecated features?

Comment: @alex Did you know that Google (www.google.com) has 32 errors in W3 Validator? The Google search engine front-page is an exception, there is a valid reason why it uses CENTER and why it has 32 errors. The general rule though is to avoid CENTER (and any other deprecated features).

Comment: @sime I'm not suggesting the use of center tag, but it is still used and by big sites. As for error validation, ebay have 458 errors, yahoo have 200 errors .... The point is center tag is still used and heavily. I gave OP 4 possible ways to center a div without suggesting anything specific.

Comment: @alex I doubt that. What other big site uses it?

Comment: @sime, that's not the point, google is enough proof being the number 1 ranking site on the web.

Comment: @alex You say that it's used heavily. You obviously cannot use just Google to prove that. My guess is (without any research) that the CENTER element is not used by any modern web-site except google.com

Comment: @sime, Why is Google not enough proof for you. Do you think it's hard for them to just do `margin:0px auto`. Honestly i can't seem to find any other big site using the center tag at the moment. But I've seen it used on big sites and google was what stuck to mind.

Comment: @alex: The Google homepage was *specifically engineered* to take the absolute minimum number of bytes; of course, it's got more convoluted since inception. The reason for that is that their homepage is viewed zillions of times per second, and even a 1 byte code size reduction adds up in bandwidth. Regardless of this, I fully agree with @Šime - you **should not** be recommending the use of the `<center>` tag here - it's just bad advice, plain and simple - for one thing it's breaking the separation of HTML (for content) and CSS (for layout). You should edit it out of your answer.

Comment: @thirtydot All the options are provided are valid centering options. i did not recommand any method over the other as your comment stated. Center tag is not bad animal. If it's used by google, i take it's not a bad thing. At last, it doesn't hurt to include all possibilities for OP to choose from specially if the user is new to HTML.

Comment: @alex: Just because it works, doesn't mean you should use it. `<center>` is not good practice to teach to someone who is "new to HTML". And, as I said in my last comment (*you seem to have mysteriously ignored this point, so I'm repeating it*) using `<center>` means you are putting your presentation logic inside your HTML - which is widely considered to be a bad thing.

Comment: @thirtydot Again, all the options are provided are valid centering options. i did not recommand any method over the other. i personally would go the css way. Regardless, it doesn't hurt to show all options.

Comment: @alex: **It does hurt** to teach *deprecated, bad practices*. Part of your answer does that, therefore you should remove that part. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 6):

Try `margin: 0 auto`, the div will need a fixed with.

Answer (score 6):

If for some reason you have position absolute on the div, do this:

```
<div class="something"></div>

.something {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `width` and `height`, you should try `margin-right: 45%;`... it is 100% working for me.. so i can take it to anywhere with percentage!

Answer (score 2):

Give the DIV a specific with in percentage or pixels and center it using CSS margin property.

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-main-div"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#my-main-div { margin: 0 auto; }
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
<style>
.center {
    margin: auto;

}
</style>

<div class="center">
    <p> somthing goes here </p>
</div>
```

[Try Online](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container)